# Change php code that runs in a batch file

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, vbscript

I am having problems when changing the php code, apparently the changes do not take effect, it is still running the same code. Is there a temporary file that i have to delete?

Im using srvany.exe on a registry to run the .bat at windows start, im not sure what the .vbs file do...

file.vbs

```
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\php\batch\file_events_speedfile_serverspeedfile.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

file_events_speedfile_serverspeedfile.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
SET PATH=C:\PHP
php C:\php\apps\file_events_speedfile\file_serverSpeedFile.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, there was a problem with paths, you need to use absolute path in php when you use files, this when you gonna run your php with .bat files.
example

```
fopen("C:\foldera\appfolder\\something.txt","w");
```

and remember use \\ before the filename

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks anyway.